# Angular changing HTML if a user is logged in

Tags: angular

So I am trying to use angular over JQuery which is a bit of a mind bender.

In my app I want to change text according to a users logged in state. If he is logged in, I want to show: My Account, and if no one is logged in I want to show: Login / Register.

Easy to do in Jquery, not quite sure the best method for NG.

HTML

```
<li>
    <a (click)="openLoginForm()">         
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login / Register</a> 
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> My Account</a> 
</li>
```

What I would like to do is check a variable: loggedIn, if true it shows "My Account", if false it shows "Login / Register".

I am not 100% clear how to do this via Angular2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, set isLogged when user logs on your component:

```
<a (click)="openLoginForm()">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> {{ isLogged ? "My Account" : "Login / Register" }}
</a>
```

This is only working as simple binding, it will not detect change so you could do somthing like this:

```
<a (click)="openLoginForm()">
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> {{ isLoggedTittle }}
    </a>
```

and in component set the title:

```
isLoggedTittle = logged ? "My Account" : "Login / Register";
```

Comment: This looks the simplest. Although I note that the change in state is not being detected. I am invoking it from ngOnInit() {...} and I see the change in the console, just not in the html...

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is only working for the first time. This is not two way binding so it doesn't detect change. You could set title in your component, like you set the flag isLogged

Comment: In the scheme of things, this does answer the original question. I will post another question for the two-way binding.

Answer (score 2):

Freshbm's answer is the better solution but i wanted to clarify what happens in `{{ isLogged ? "My Account" : "Login / Register" }}`

`isLogged` is usually a boolean of true or false but can be a value

`?` is a check

`"My Account"` if the boolean is true or the value is valid

`:` means if false, undefined or null, do this

`"Login / Register"` if the boolean is false or the value is null or undefined

Answer (score -1):

In your situation the ideal solution is to use `ngIf`:

```
<li>        
    <a (click)="openLoginForm()" *ngIf="!loggedIn"> 
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login / Register</a> 
    <a (click)="openMyAccountForm()" *ngIf="loggedIn"> 
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> My Account</a> 
</li>
```

This will show the My Account section if `loggedIn` is true, and Login/Register if false.

By using two different anchor tags entirely you can completely change how each one behaves, what icon is inside them etc.