# conditional set angular/nativescript nsRouterLink

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to set a `nsRouterLink` only when a specific condition is true?

Let's assume, I have a list view and each item gets its own `nsRouterLink` to a detail page. But some items in the list do not have the id needed for the detail, so they should simply not be clickable while the others should.

I know that I could just use an `onClick` binding and handle it on my own, but is that possible with `nsRouterLink` automatically, too?

For example:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items">
    <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/path/' + item.id]">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: you could try switchable bindings, that should work with nsrouterlink

Comment: I'm more or less new to angular, so could you add an example please?

Comment: `[nsRouterLink]="<value to check> ? '<value if true>' : '<value if false>' "`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578109/angular-changing-html-if-a-user-is-logged-in/42578290#42578290 for an example

Comment: The problem is that if the condition is false there should be no link at all.

Comment: thats not true, the value if false can still be a router link

Comment: It could, but shouldn't in my case.

Comment: what should it be if the condition is false?

Comment: then nothing should happen. You should only be able to click on items with correct ids because only these items could have detail views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is with this solution I saw several times:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items">
    <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="[item?.id ? '/path/' + item.id : false]">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: It worked for me when I set it to return null instead of false

Comment: It did not work at all for me, throwing an error if I was giving false or null.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `nsRouterLink` much.
But what occurs when you leave the link in `null` or `undefined`?

If you really handle the link on a `click` event, then conditionally listening to the event should be done on the code side, that mean the component.

Another option is to have 2 different components shown.

- if detail → show `nsRouterLink`
- if no detail → show label.

Something like that can work also.

Comment: Do you think of a notification like "there are no data to display"?

Comment: I guess, that could be handled in the detail component rather than the list itself...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isEnabled` property, that will disable the button if the user isn't allowed to go to the next page

```
<Button [isEnabled]="<value to check>" text="<Text>" [nsRouterLink]="['/<link>']"></Button>
```

Comment: it's not a button, it's a whole StackLayout which surrounds the item content. I guess, I should add this to the question.

Comment: You cant do what youre wanting if you use an ngfor, not easily atleast

Comment: How do you mean that respectively what would be the problem you are talking about?

Comment: if you bind the stacklayout's `[isEnabled]=""` to a value, all the layouts will either be enabled or disabled at the same time

Comment: So your critic concerns more your answer than my needs^^ it's just about setting an attribute or leave it out of the element tag

Comment: do you always want the layout/button to be there?

Comment: There have to be a layout to display the item, but it should only be clickable if a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: yeah, theres no easy way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Adding `false` or `null` gives error something like:

> ERROR Error: NG04008: The requested path contains null segment at index 0

**AND**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/false'

> Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/false'`  what really worked for without any error:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items">
    <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="item.id ? ['/path/' + item.id] : []">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```